# python selenium opens new browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm signed in to Whatsapp (from the main browser)
then i coded the message bot in selenium but then when i opened it a new browser was opened.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
```

When the site opened, it wasn't logged in in the browser, but I did.

Comment: You open a new browser with Selenium that goes to "https://web.whatsapp.com/". This means it will not be logged in if you already logged in to another browser. You have to add the login steps to your script.

Comment: but ı dont wanna login because ı already did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the profile data. You can get the Profile data using `edge://version`

[image]

Copy the path and paste it after `user-data-dir=`

Also the path is something like this `...\...\...\Edge\User Data\Default` so remove the last dir name like this `Edge\User Data`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=PATH/TO/PROFILE/DATA",)
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)

driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
```

- If you get any error like

> unknown error: Microsoft Edge failed to start: exited normally.
> (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

So, Use chrome: To get the data path `chrome://version`
Paste the dir path after `used-data-dir` and remove `/Default` from the path

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=PATH/TO/PROFILE/DATA",)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
```

Comment: If you get any other error, comment it down.

Comment: @HasanCb You paste the `executable path` not the Profile path.

Comment: @HasanCb See the above image The one I mention You have to paste that path. (Red Line)

Comment: Tell me if you get into another problem...

Comment: well. AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Profile 3
why does it write like that

Comment: Remove `\Profile 3` from the path

Comment: how can ı delete

Comment: @HasanCb Your string in `add_argument` will looks like this `r"Useruser-data-dir=C:\Users\YouUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data"`

Comment: okay i did it. But ı always open it for profile 1 and in new browser.

Comment: What Your string in the `add_arguments`. Remove your username if you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250487/discussion-between-codester-09-and-hasan-cb).

Comment: options.add_argument(r"Useruser-data-dir=C:\Users\hck\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data",)

Comment: @HasanCb Your path is wrong. Where is your username in the path

Comment: it didnt worked in chrome

Comment: What error you got

Comment: And what string you put in `add_argument`

Comment: Make sure you put the string from the `chrome://version` not the edge

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250487/discussion-between-codester-09-and-hasan-cb).